# Rails 4 ActiveRecord Transaction Block - Rollback criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions, postgresql-9.1

Hi i am using the ActiveRecords Transaction block to make a bunch of records either get all accepted or none.
I included the transaction block inside my model and call the whole function from a controller:

```
  def self.write_atomic_union_sync
   Union.transaction do
     @sync=Sync.create(sync_date: DateTime.now, user_id: user_id)
     union_array.map do |t|
        Union.create(value2: t[:value2], user_id:t[:user_id],value1: t[:value1],sync_id: @sync[:id])
        #sync.unions.create(t)
     end
   end
  end
```

I have some constraints on the `Union`, to avoid duplicated entries.
When i send my test data for the first time  a sync object with the union records get stored to the database. However when i commit the same data again,
the unions get not saved but the sync gets written.

From the [Ruby API guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) it is valid to use the  create method within the transaction block, but i also tried with calling `@sync.new` and `unions.new` over the array  before and then put only `@sync.save!` etc. inside the Transaction block without much success either.

I think its maybe because there is no explicit ROLLBACK exception from the union-create procedure. But i cant figure out why..
maybe someone has a helpful clue?
Thanks to all in advance!

```
(1.2ms)  BEGIN
 Transaction Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "union" WHERE    ("union"."user_id" = 18 AND "union"."value1" =1111 AND "union"."value2" IS NULL) LIMIT 1

 SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "syncs" ("sync_date", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["sync_date","2016-01-13 21:04:48.175245"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-01-13 21:04:48.213958"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-13 21:04:48.213958"]]

 Transaction Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "transactions" WHERE ("transactions"."user_id" = 18 AND "transactions"."value1" =
 22222 AND "transactions"."value2" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
(27.4ms)  COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction block will only rollback if an exception is raised. You want to use the version of `create` that yields an exception on failure: `create!`. This way, if one of the creations fails, it will raise an exception that will trigger the rollback. Note that the exception will be propagated beyond the transaction block, so you will have to catch it on the outside. Try:

```
  def self.write_atomic_union_sync
    begin
      Union.transaction do
        @sync=Sync.create!(sync_date: DateTime.now, user_id: user_id)
        union_array.map do |t|
           Union.create!(value2: t[:value2], user_id:t[:user_id],value1: t[:value1],sync_id: @sync[:id])
           #sync.unions.create!(t)
        end
      end
    rescue
      # Handle the exception
    end
  end
```